# coffeescript class - calling calling one class method from an other

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks

I have rewritten my embedded JS in my rails app to coffeescript..and I am new to coffeescript...

My approach is a mix of these articles:

- [approach one](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/organizing-javascript-in-rails-application-with-turbolinks/)
- [approach two](https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/)

My code:

```
s = undefined
class App.PhotoLike

  settings:
    modalElement: $('#myModal')
    likeButtonId: '#like'
    photo_id: $('.image_info').attr('photo_id')
    numberOfLikes: $('#likes_num')

  constructor: (@el) ->
    console.log('constructor called')
    s = @settings
    @bindUIActions()
    return this


  bindUIActions: ->
    console.log('bindUIActions called')
    $('#myModal').on 'click', '#like', -> likePhoto()
    $(document).on "page:change", -> pageChange()


  pageChange: ->
    console.log('pageChange called')
    photo = new App.Photo

  likePhoto: ->
    console.log('likePhoto called')
    url = '/photos/' + s.photo_id + '/like'
    $.get url, (data) ->
      s.numberOfLikes.html data['likes'] + ' likes'
      $(s.likeButtonId).toggleClass 'btn-success'
```

This is part of a model that gets loded with ajax and once that call succeeds i do i create the above class (instance of):

```
new (App.PhotoLike)
```

My problem.
The modal gets loaded an all seems good. But when I trigger the event:

```
$('#myModal').on 'click', '#like', -> likePhoto()
```

I get:

```
photo.like.self-942fcd8….js?body=1:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: likePhoto is not defined
```

so, it does not know the likePhoto function. I have tried calling this.likePhoto and @likePhoto, but this refers to the button element that triggers the event.

So how do I do this?
Other approaches are welcome. i not really sure that I need the classes...but I really want structured code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

likePhoto() is a function of our object/class `App.PhotoLike`. And you're calling it like a local function.

You can do something like this instead

```
bindUIActions: ->
  _this = this #this will change inside, so we have to have a reference to our object here
  console.log('bindUIActions called')
  $('#myModal').on 'click', '#like', -> _this.likePhoto()
  ...
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yay..it works...so simple! Can you help me on a follow up question...how do I get the s (settings) variable to work as intended inside the class

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean as intended. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have the settings variable at the top of the class where I set various settings needed I the class. So I want to use those settings in the class e.g. Settings.url

Comment: I guess you can directly use from settings. `url = '/photos/' + @settings.photo_id + '/like'`. That should work fine, unless your scope changes from current object to the window or anything else. In that case you can make a reference `_this = @` at the top of your function to be used later. Hope it helps.

Comment: You can also put your settings inside an initialize function to make sure they are available when your object is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Kumar's answer, you can use fat arrows to bind `@` to `this`:

```
bindUIActions: =>
  console.log('bindUIActions called')
  $('#myModal').on 'click', '#like', -> @likePhoto()
```

Try that.